# Is there something like a "placeholder" as element in arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a certain numpy 1d - array with a fixed number of elements with which I am doing some mathematical operations. When one of the elements becomes zero, I want to delete it, but instead of making the size of the 1d - array smaller, I need to fill temporarily with a placeholder. By placeholder, I mean something that it will determine in the future that the next element will be put in this specific position and not at the end of the array.

Specifically what I am doing now is the following:

```
delete_ind = np.where(element == 0)[0]
array = np.delete(array, delete_ind)

...

array = np.append(array, new_element)
```

But this shifts the values to the left, while I want to fill the delete_ind with blank and then go back and put in the blank position the new_element.

Comment: You can  use numpy.nan to fill those positions

Comment: `delete` and `append` make new arrays, and are more expensive than the equivalent list methods.  Are you sure you need an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.where to  find the indices you want to replace. Then, once you have calculated the new values to be inserted (assuming these depend on the index) you can use np.where again to insert them

```
#find the indices we want to replace
fill_inds = np.where(a == 0)

#build an array with the values to be inserted into a
fill_values = np.zeros(a.shape)
fill_values[fill_inds] = 100 #this could be some function of the index if you like

#replace the values we want to replace
a = np.where(a == 0, fill_values, a)
```

If fill_values is a constant you can use np.where directly. If you want to do stuff with a before you insert your new values you can use a masked array

```
mask = a == 0 #Array of true/false values
masked_a = np.ma.masked_array(a, mask)

# do stuff to a, without touching the masked values

filled_a = masked_a.filled(fill_value = 'some value')
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
delete_ind = np.where(element == 0)[0]
array = np.delete(array, delete_ind)
```

instead you could do this

```
array[delete_ind]=NaN
```